# Setnextsubsubsection in beamer class

Tags: beamer, sectioning, numbering

I need to set the subsubsection number manually in beamer class and therefore use this code:

```
\newcommand{\setnextsubsubsection}[1]{%
  \setcounter{subsubsection}{\numexpr#1-1\relax}%
  \beamer@tocsubsubsectionnumber=\numexpr#1\relax\space}
```

The same code works fine for sections but when I use `\setnextsubsubsection` it says

> `!undefined control sequence. \setnextsubsubsection` ...

Is it because `\beamer@tocsubsubsectionnumber =` does not work?

Here a (hopefully) minimal example:

```
\documentclass[mathserif, handout]{beamer}

\usepackage[polish,german]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\linespread{1.1}\Large}
\newcommand{\sectiontitle}{\huge \bf \color{blau} \thesection . \insertsection}
\newcommand{\subsectiontitle}{\thesubsection . \subsecname}
\newcommand{\subsubsectiontitle}{\thesubsubsection . \subsubsecname }


\defbeamertemplate{subsubsection in toc}{subsubsections numbered}
{\leavevmode\tiny\leftskip=3em%
 \rlap{\hskip-3em\inserttocsectionnumber.\inserttocsubsectionnumber.\inserttocsubsubsectionnumber}%
 \inserttocsubsubsection\par}
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}[subsections numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{subsubsection in toc}[subsubsections numbered]

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\setnextsection}[1]{%
  \setcounter{section}{\numexpr#1-1\relax}%
  \beamer@tocsectionnumber=\numexpr#1-1\relax\space}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\setnextsubsubsection}[1]{%
  \setcounter{subsubsection}{\numexpr#1-1\relax}%
  \beamer@tocsubsubsectionnumber=\numexpr#1\relax\space}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\makeatother


\makeatletter
\long\def\beamer@section[#1]#2{%
  \beamer@savemode%
  \mode<all>%
  \ifbeamer@inlecture
    \refstepcounter{section}%
    \beamer@ifempty{#2}%
    {\long\def\secname{#1}\long\def\lastsection{#1}}%
    {\global\advance\beamer@tocsectionnumber by 1\relax%
      \long\def\secname{#2}%
      \long\def\lastsection{#1}%
      \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\beamer@sectionintoc{\the\c@section}{#2\hfill\the\c@page}{\the\c@page}{\the\c@part}%
        {\the\beamer@tocsectionnumber}}}%
    {\let\\=\relax\xdef\sectionlink{{Navigation\the\c@page}{\noexpand\secname}}}%
    \beamer@tempcount=\c@page\advance\beamer@tempcount by -1%
    \beamer@ifempty{#1}{}{%
      \addtocontents{nav}{\protect\headcommand{\protect\sectionentry{\the\c@section}{#1}{\the\c@page}{\secname}{\the\c@part}}}%
      \addtocontents{nav}{\protect\headcommand{\protect\beamer@sectionpages{\the\beamer@sectionstartpage}{\the\beamer@tempcount}}}%
      \addtocontents{nav}{\protect\headcommand{\protect\beamer@subsectionpages{\the\beamer@subsectionstartpage}{\the\beamer@tempcount}}}%
    }%
    \beamer@sectionstartpage=\c@page%
    \beamer@subsectionstartpage=\c@page%
    \def\insertsection{\expandafter\hyperlink\sectionlink}%
    \def\insertsubsection{}%
    \def\insertsubsubsection{}%
    \def\insertsectionhead{\hyperlink{Navigation\the\c@page}{#1}}%
    \def\insertsubsectionhead{}%
    \def\insertsubsubsectionhead{}%
    \def\lastsubsection{}%
    \Hy@writebookmark{\the\c@section}{\secname}{Outline\the\c@part.\the\c@section}{2}{toc}%
    \hyper@anchorstart{Outline\the\c@part.\the\c@section}\hyper@anchorend%
    \beamer@ifempty{#2}{\beamer@atbeginsections}{\beamer@atbeginsection}%
  \fi%
  \beamer@resumemode}%

\def\beamer@subsection[#1]#2{%
  \beamer@savemode%
  \mode<all>%
  \ifbeamer@inlecture%
    \refstepcounter{subsection}%
    \beamer@ifempty{#2}{\long\def\subsecname{#1}\long\def\lastsubsection{#1}}
    {%
      \long\def\subsecname{#2}%
      \long\def\lastsubsection{#1}%
      \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\beamer@subsectionintoc{\the\c@section}{\the\c@subsection}{#2\hfill\the\c@page}{\the\c@page}{\the\c@part}{\the\beamer@tocsectionnumber}}%
    }%
    \beamer@tempcount=\c@page\advance\beamer@tempcount by -1%
    \addtocontents{nav}{%
      \protect\headcommand{\protect\beamer@subsectionentry{\the\c@part}{\the\c@section}{\the\c@subsection}{\the\c@page}{\lastsubsection}}%
      \protect\headcommand{\protect\beamer@subsectionpages{\the\beamer@subsectionstartpage}{\the\beamer@tempcount}}%
    }%
    \beamer@subsectionstartpage=\c@page%
    \edef\subsectionlink{{Navigation\the\c@page}{\noexpand\subsecname}}%
    \def\insertsubsection{\expandafter\hyperlink\subsectionlink}%
    \def\insertsubsubsection{}%
    \def\insertsubsectionhead{\hyperlink{Navigation\the\c@page}{#1}}%
    \def\insertsubsubsectionhead{}%
    \Hy@writebookmark{\the\c@subsection}{#2}{Outline\the\c@part.\the\c@section.\the\c@subsection.\the\c@page}{3}{toc}%
    \hyper@anchorstart{Outline\the\c@part.\the\c@section.\the\c@subsection.\the\c@page}\hyper@anchorend%
    \beamer@ifempty{#2}{\beamer@atbeginsubsections}{\beamer@atbeginsubsection}%
  \fi%
  \beamer@resumemode}

\def\beamer@subsubsection[#1]#2{%
  \beamer@savemode%
  \mode<all>%
  \ifbeamer@inlecture%
    \refstepcounter{subsubsection}%
    \beamer@ifempty{#2}{\long\def\subsubsecname{#1}\long\def\lastsubsubsection{#1}}
    {%
      \long\def\subsubsecname{#2}%
      \long\def\lastsubsubsection{#1}%
      \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\beamer@subsubsectionintoc%
        {\the\c@section}{\the\c@subsection}{\the\c@subsubsection}{#2\hfill\the\c@page}{\the\c@page}{\the\c@part}{\the\beamer@tocsectionnumber}}%
    }%
    \addtocontents{nav}{\protect\headcommand{\protect\beamer@subsubsectionentry%
        {\the\c@part}{\the\c@section}{\the\c@subsection}{\the\c@subsubsection}{\the\c@page}{\lastsubsubsection}}}%
    \edef\subsubsectionlink{{Navigation\the\c@page}{\noexpand\subsubsecname}}%
    \def\insertsubsubsection{\expandafter\hyperlink\subsubsectionlink}%
    \def\insertsubsubsectionhead{#1}%
    \Hy@writebookmark{\the\c@subsubsection}{#2}{Outline\the\c@part.\the\c@section.\the\c@subsection.\the\c@subsubsection.\the\c@page}{4}{toc}%
    \hyper@anchorstart{Outline\the\c@part.\the\c@section.\the\c@subsection.\the\c@subsubsection.\the\c@page}\hyper@anchorend%
    \beamer@ifempty{#2}{\beamer@atbeginsubsubsections}{\beamer@atbeginsubsubsection}%
  \fi%
  \beamer@resumemode}
\makeatother

\renewcommand*{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand*{\thesubsubsection}{\thesubsection.\arabic{subsubsection}}

\begin{document}

%\setnextsubsubsection{7}
\subsubsection{test}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\subsubsectiontitle}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That was what I feared. But how can I access the table of content counter for subsubsections? Is there a possibility to set the subsubsection manually and also correct the table of content accordingly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I think I worked it out.

`beamer` just uses the `subsubsection` counter and no `\beamer@tocsubsubsectionnumber` count. It seems to suffice to use the following definition:

```
\newcommand{\setnextsubsubsection}[1]{%
  \setcounter{subsubsection}{\numexpr#1-1\relax}}
```

In your complete code:

```
\documentclass[mathserif, handout]{beamer}

\usepackage[polish,german]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\linespread{1.1}\Large}
\newcommand{\sectiontitle}{\huge \bf \color{blau} \thesection . \insertsection}
\newcommand{\subsectiontitle}{\thesubsection . \subsecname}
\newcommand{\subsubsectiontitle}{\thesubsubsection . \subsubsecname }


\defbeamertemplate{subsubsection in toc}{subsubsections numbered}
{\leavevmode\tiny\leftskip=3em%
 \rlap{\hskip-3em\inserttocsectionnumber.\inserttocsubsectionnumber.\inserttocsubsubsectionnumber}%
 \inserttocsubsubsection\par}
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}[subsections numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{subsubsection in toc}[subsubsections numbered]

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\setnextsection}[1]{%
  \setcounter{section}{\numexpr#1-1\relax}%
  \beamer@tocsectionnumber=\numexpr#1-1\relax\space}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\setnextsubsubsection}[1]{%
  \setcounter{subsubsection}{\numexpr#1-1\relax}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\makeatother


\makeatletter
\long\def\beamer@section[#1]#2{%
  \beamer@savemode%
  \mode<all>%
  \ifbeamer@inlecture
    \refstepcounter{section}%
    \beamer@ifempty{#2}%
    {\long\def\secname{#1}\long\def\lastsection{#1}}%
    {\global\advance\beamer@tocsectionnumber by 1\relax%
      \long\def\secname{#2}%
      \long\def\lastsection{#1}%
      \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\beamer@sectionintoc{\the\c@section}{#2\hfill\the\c@page}{\the\c@page}{\the\c@part}%
        {\the\beamer@tocsectionnumber}}}%
    {\let\\=\relax\xdef\sectionlink{{Navigation\the\c@page}{\noexpand\secname}}}%
    \beamer@tempcount=\c@page\advance\beamer@tempcount by -1%
    \beamer@ifempty{#1}{}{%
      \addtocontents{nav}{\protect\headcommand{\protect\sectionentry{\the\c@section}{#1}{\the\c@page}{\secname}{\the\c@part}}}%
      \addtocontents{nav}{\protect\headcommand{\protect\beamer@sectionpages{\the\beamer@sectionstartpage}{\the\beamer@tempcount}}}%
      \addtocontents{nav}{\protect\headcommand{\protect\beamer@subsectionpages{\the\beamer@subsectionstartpage}{\the\beamer@tempcount}}}%
    }%
    \beamer@sectionstartpage=\c@page%
    \beamer@subsectionstartpage=\c@page%
    \def\insertsection{\expandafter\hyperlink\sectionlink}%
    \def\insertsubsection{}%
    \def\insertsubsubsection{}%
    \def\insertsectionhead{\hyperlink{Navigation\the\c@page}{#1}}%
    \def\insertsubsectionhead{}%
    \def\insertsubsubsectionhead{}%
    \def\lastsubsection{}%
    \Hy@writebookmark{\the\c@section}{\secname}{Outline\the\c@part.\the\c@section}{2}{toc}%
    \hyper@anchorstart{Outline\the\c@part.\the\c@section}\hyper@anchorend%
    \beamer@ifempty{#2}{\beamer@atbeginsections}{\beamer@atbeginsection}%
  \fi%
  \beamer@resumemode}%

\def\beamer@subsection[#1]#2{%
  \beamer@savemode%
  \mode<all>%
  \ifbeamer@inlecture%
    \refstepcounter{subsection}%
    \beamer@ifempty{#2}{\long\def\subsecname{#1}\long\def\lastsubsection{#1}}
    {%
      \long\def\subsecname{#2}%
      \long\def\lastsubsection{#1}%
      \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\beamer@subsectionintoc{\the\c@section}{\the\c@subsection}{#2\hfill\the\c@page}{\the\c@page}{\the\c@part}{\the\beamer@tocsectionnumber}}%
    }%
    \beamer@tempcount=\c@page\advance\beamer@tempcount by -1%
    \addtocontents{nav}{%
      \protect\headcommand{\protect\beamer@subsectionentry{\the\c@part}{\the\c@section}{\the\c@subsection}{\the\c@page}{\lastsubsection}}%
      \protect\headcommand{\protect\beamer@subsectionpages{\the\beamer@subsectionstartpage}{\the\beamer@tempcount}}%
    }%
    \beamer@subsectionstartpage=\c@page%
    \edef\subsectionlink{{Navigation\the\c@page}{\noexpand\subsecname}}%
    \def\insertsubsection{\expandafter\hyperlink\subsectionlink}%
    \def\insertsubsubsection{}%
    \def\insertsubsectionhead{\hyperlink{Navigation\the\c@page}{#1}}%
    \def\insertsubsubsectionhead{}%
    \Hy@writebookmark{\the\c@subsection}{#2}{Outline\the\c@part.\the\c@section.\the\c@subsection.\the\c@page}{3}{toc}%
    \hyper@anchorstart{Outline\the\c@part.\the\c@section.\the\c@subsection.\the\c@page}\hyper@anchorend%
    \beamer@ifempty{#2}{\beamer@atbeginsubsections}{\beamer@atbeginsubsection}%
  \fi%
  \beamer@resumemode}

\def\beamer@subsubsection[#1]#2{%
  \beamer@savemode%
  \mode<all>%
  \ifbeamer@inlecture%
    \refstepcounter{subsubsection}%
    \beamer@ifempty{#2}{\long\def\subsubsecname{#1}\long\def\lastsubsubsection{#1}}
    {%
      \long\def\subsubsecname{#2}%
      \long\def\lastsubsubsection{#1}%
      \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\beamer@subsubsectionintoc%
        {\the\c@section}{\the\c@subsection}{\the\c@subsubsection}{#2\hfill\the\c@page}{\the\c@page}{\the\c@part}{\the\beamer@tocsectionnumber}}%
    }%
    \addtocontents{nav}{\protect\headcommand{\protect\beamer@subsubsectionentry%
        {\the\c@part}{\the\c@section}{\the\c@subsection}{\the\c@subsubsection}{\the\c@page}{\lastsubsubsection}}}%
    \edef\subsubsectionlink{{Navigation\the\c@page}{\noexpand\subsubsecname}}%
    \def\insertsubsubsection{\expandafter\hyperlink\subsubsectionlink}%
    \def\insertsubsubsectionhead{#1}%
    \Hy@writebookmark{\the\c@subsubsection}{#2}{Outline\the\c@part.\the\c@section.\the\c@subsection.\the\c@subsubsection.\the\c@page}{4}{toc}%
    \hyper@anchorstart{Outline\the\c@part.\the\c@section.\the\c@subsection.\the\c@subsubsection.\the\c@page}\hyper@anchorend%
    \beamer@ifempty{#2}{\beamer@atbeginsubsubsections}{\beamer@atbeginsubsubsection}%
  \fi%
  \beamer@resumemode}
\makeatother

\renewcommand*{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand*{\thesubsubsection}{\thesubsection.\arabic{subsubsection}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Table of Contents}{}%>>>
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}%<<<

\setnextsubsubsection{7}
\subsubsection{test}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\subsubsectiontitle}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Results:
[image]
[image]

Still the `beamer` manual advices to not use `\subsubsection`s at all (and claims that you'll give better presentations if you do as you're said).